# MVC4 razor fill dropdownlist with data from json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two dropdownlists for  Languages and Countries

On selecting a language in the dropdownlist, should fill corresponding countries in the country dropdownlist

```
 @Html.DropDownList("LanguageSelectList", null, null, new { @class = "hyper-select fixedwidth300"})
@Html.DropDownList("CountrySelectList", null, null, new { @class = "hyper-select fixedwidth300" })
```

Here is my jquery script

```
 $("#LanguageSelectList").change(function (event) {
            $("#languageValidator").hide();
            var selectedLanguage = $("#LanguageSelectList").val();
            debugger;
            //--------
            if (selectedLanguage!='') {
                var url = '@Url.Action("GetCountryListByLanguage", "Options")';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: { selectedLanguage: selectedLanguage },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    global: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                        var ddlCountrylist = $("#CountrySelectList");
                        debugger;
                        var jsonString =JSON.stringify(data);  
                        //here how to take data from jsonstring to countries dropdownlist


                    }

                });

            } else {  
                alert('no country returnned');


            }

            //--------------

        });
```

I am able to retrieve the **expected list of countries in the json data as given below** .Now how do I fill my country dropdownlist.

```
jsonString="[{\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"n/a\",\"Value\":\"\"},{\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"China\",\"Value\":\"CN\"},{\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"Hong Kong\",\"Value\":\"HK\"},{\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"Singapore\",\"Value\":\"SG\"},{\"Selected\":false,\"Text\":\"Taiwan\",\"Value\":\"TW\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your success handler just iterate thru the returned array and add an option to drop down list for each element in the array.

```
ddlCountrylist.find('option').remove(); 
$(data).each(function(i,v){
     $('<option value='+v.Value+'>'+v.Text+'</option>').appendTo(ddlCountrylist);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In the success section of your ajax call to the controller method, you can write the below code:

```
success: function (data) {
$('#CountrySelectList').empty();
$.each(data.agent, function() {
    $('#CountrySelectList').append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: this.Value,
            html: this.Text
        })
    );    
});
```

}

I have not tested the above code, but I hope this would definitely work